# Mac SQLite editor

Tags: macos, user-interface, sqlite

I am aware of [CocoaMySQL](http://cocoamysql.sourceforge.net/) but I have not seen a Mac GUI for SQLite, is there one?

My Google search didn't turn up any Mac related GUI's which is why I'm asking here rather than Google.

Comment: As an update: CocoaMySQL is now "Sequel Pro" and it's awesome for MySQL on the mac. It's still being actively developed and they have plans for SQLite and Postgres, but they aren't available yet.

Comment: @philfreo +1 - until that happens, I'm sticking with the command line shell and/or Writing scripts to do what I want. :)

Comment: Sequel Pro is still not SQLite, but here is the link http://www.sequelpro.com/

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[SQLite Manager for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)

Comment: Hangs on slow running queries and had no cancel query button. I use RazorSQL.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't allow you to alter existing tables.

Comment: I would say, having used MSSQL, Oracle Toad and phpMyAdmin, SQLiteManager for FireFox is by far the best one I've used. All most common operations are just there in front of you. Recently I began using Sequel Pro which is similar to SQLite Manager for Firefox and seems very clean so far as well (but that's for MySQL, not SQLite yet)

Comment: Anyone can open sqlite with password

Comment: This used to be the best, but it doesn't work with the latest firefox.

Comment: SQlite manager is giving me big headache sir , it even shows primary key same for multiple rows ,thats bizarre isn't it

Answer (score 133):

[Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) is younger than your question, and definitely feels like a 1.0, but the user experience is *miles* better than the experience of using any of the "cross-platform" apps on a Mac.

http://menial.co.uk/software/base/

I recommend you buy a license before the developer realizes he is charging too little for it.

UPDATE: Since December 2008, Base is now up to version 2.1, it has become an excellent product. I don't remember what it used to cost, but I paid for the 1.x to 2.x upgrade. Still highly recommended.

ANOTHER UPDATE: [Base is available on the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base/id402383384?mt=12), you may find it useful to read the reviews there.

Comment: I did :) It's very nice software.

Comment: I bought Base and I really love it. Perfect tool. Love all of the native controls.

Comment: nice software but not free. :(

Comment: There are plenty of free alternatives, but they are not as nice. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: just purchased...its a winner

Comment: Looks excellent, trialling it at the moment and does everything I'd want to do all while also having a nicely designed Mac app UI.

Comment: I purchased too.  Nice OSX app.

Comment: The UI is really not all that good, app seems to lack features and its quite expensive for what it really is. I'm glad its a solution for you guys, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you want an alternative to Base, look at http://alternativeto.net/software/base/

Comment: I have just purchased Base and I can say that it is one of the best purchases I've ever made. Great editor.

Answer (score 90):

I use [Liya](https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12) from the Mac App Store, it's free, does the job, and the project is maintained (a month or so between updates as of Jan 2013).

I also test a lot on the device.  You can access the SQLITE database on the device by:

1. Add `Application supports iTunes file sharing` to the info.plist and setting it to YES
2. Running the app on a device
3. Open iTunes
4. Select the device
5. Select the "Apps" tab
6. Scroll down to the "File Sharing" section and select the app
7. The .sqlite file should appear in the right hand pane - select it and "Save to..."
8. Once it's saved open it up in your favourite SQLITE editor

You can also edit it and copy it back.

**EDIT:
You can also do this through the Organizer in XCode**

1. Open the Organizer in XCode (Window > Organiser)
2. Select the "Devices" tab
3. Expand the device on the left that you want to download/upload data to
4. Select Applications
5. Select an Application in the main panel
6. The panel at the bottom (Data files in Sandbox) will update with all the files within that application
7. Choose Download and save it somewhere
8. Find the file in Finder
9. Right click and select "Show Package Contents"

You can now view, edit, and re-upload the package to your debug device.
This can be really handy for keeping snapshots of different states to try out on other devices.

Comment: This one's a lot newer than any of the others. Looks like it's being developed pretty actively. So compared to the other free options, this looks quite promising.

Comment: Welp, nevermind. I can't get Liya to display any contents of any table for me. Thank god I use Firefox anyway. I would rescind my upvote, but hey, SO has so many moronic rules now that it won't let me do that!!

Comment: Admittedly Liya has a quirky interface.  You did remember to select the table and click the big "Go" button at the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, with either "Go" or "Run Custom Query" all I could get was an endless busy spinner. I don't know what's wrong. I would definitely use it if I can figure it out.

Comment: Liya is perfect. Thx for the link. Just installed version 2.0.12 on OSX 10.8 and it works great.

Answer (score 65):

You may like [SQLPro for SQLite](https://sqlitepro.com/?source=stackoverflow) (previously SQLite Professional - [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlite-professional/id586001240?ls=1&mt=12)).

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
- Versions Integration (rollback to previous versions).
- Inline data filtering.
- The ability to load [sqlite extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html).
- SQLite 2 Compatibility.
- Exporting options to CSV, JSON, XML and MySQL.
- Importing from CSV, JSON or XML.
- Column reordering.
- Full screen support.

[image: SQLPro for SQLite overview screenshot]

There is a seven day trial available [via the website](https://sqlitepro.com/?source=stackoverflow). If you purchase via our [website](https://sqlitepro.com/store.php), use the promo code **STACK25** to save 25%.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Comment: I'm seeing v1.0.3 on the AppStore and currently priced at $8.99. Is the free version no longer available? Thanks.

Comment: @paul_sns, unfortunately the app is no longer free. Here are some promo codes though: PRFKTLYJTE3M, 7PN6FHANKNAJ, KY7KJPTMKJAA, WAFRTR797AWK, 64PY7K36TFY4 and if they run out I can give a promo code to anyone who emails me/support with a link to this page.

Comment: Any chance of getting some more promo codes? Would certainly let people know about this if it turns out to be as good as it looks Would be nice if a promo code also had an option to pay for the product afterwards.

Comment: Very cool app. Worth the download.

Comment: Really great app! Saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Did not catch twitter promo codes, any chance to get any? Limited version seems good to me, but i would probably try the full one. Also in App Store is older one then the one from the webpage.

Comment: A fantastic OSX app - a lot of work and thought went into this. Good value.

Answer (score 22):

MesaSQLite is the best I've found so far.

[www.desertsandsoftware.com](http://www.desertsandsoftware.com/)

Looks very promising indeed.

Comment: my vote goes to MesaSQLite too, not the best interface but it works

Comment: Website is dead? Not very promising anymore...

Comment: MesaSQLite is a free tool for sqlite on mac. (MesaSQL for windows is not free). Base is beautiful but is too expensive.

Comment: Rather nice and free solution.

Comment: Ignore the "website dead" comment.  It is up as of the datetime of this comment.

Comment: Currently it's $20 shareware, not free.

Comment: This was such a pain to use.

Answer (score 18):

I am using simple tool for basic sqlite operation called [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58)

This tool is based on Adobe Air so that must be installed prior to use of Lita. Adobe air can be downloaded for free from [Adobe site](http://www.adobe.com).

Comment: This is a really great tool.  I love that it is an Air app, and that I only have to open it when I need it.  Really nice simple GUI.  Just what I wanted!
[here is a screen](http://i.imgur.com/lSnO9.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems it stopped working on Lion.

Comment: This project is now discontinued :(

Comment: It still works on Yosemite...

Answer (score 14):

That FireFox extension looks pretty nice. I've used [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) in the past and it did the job.

Comment: SQLite Browser is kinda old but works just fine, and less of a commitment than firefox plugin (I use Safari, not use firefox)

Comment: I like the cross-platform [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/). It's simple and fast.

Comment: And free. Don't forget that part.

Answer (score 13):

I've published instructions for how to run the [Firefox SQLite Manager](http://www.kiveo.net/blog/mac-sqlite-manager-standalone-app/) outside of Firefox, since FF hase become so bloated in the last few releases. It's really easy and I've even compiled a DMG for the sqlite gui if anyone wants it.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Works perfectly on Snow Leo, and it was so easy... just install the XULRunner framework, drag your SQLite Manager app package to the apps folder, and voila! No need to fuss with the terminal or anything. Now all it needs is a fancy icon! I think I'll steal the one from Base for now... :P

Comment: Doesn't work on Lion. I installed the latest XULRunner, and tried running the app installer myself, and using Jeremy's already made .dmg

Answer (score 8):

Take a look on a free tool - Valentina Studio. Amazing product!  IMO this is the best manager for SQLite for all platforms:

- http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview

Also it works on Mac OS X, you can install Valentina Studio (FREE) directly from Mac App Store:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/valentina-studio/id604825918?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: It was useful for me.

Answer (score 5):

[Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) is my current preference: It uses QT, so it's cross-platform. Since I develop on Windows, Linux and OS X, it helps to have the same tools available on each.

I also tried [SQLite Admin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) (Windows, so irrelevant to the question anyway) for a while, but it seems unmaintained these days, and has the most annoying hotkeys of any application I've ever used - Ctrl-S clears the current query, with no hope of undo.

Comment: sudo port install sqliteman

Comment: brew install sqliteman - if homebrew is your thing instead of macports

Answer (score 5):

There is also Induction app (http://inductionapp.com/), which is free & open source (https://github.com/Induction/Induction).

Just drag & drop your .sqlite file on the icon to open the file.

And the other great option is https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility

Comment: doesn't look like Induction allows you to alter tables.

Answer (score 4):

Try this [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

See full document [here](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).
This is very simple and fast database browser for SQLite.

Comment: [Updated link](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). I prefer this one for quick edits, rather than launching Firefox just to edit a couple of rows.

Comment: This is my favorite too, it's even in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 3):

Try a [versiontracker search](http://www.versiontracker.com/php/qs.php?mode=basic&action=search&str=sqlite&srchArea=macosx&submit=Go) instead. [SqliteManager from SQLabs](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php) ($49, Mac & Windows) is the one I prefer, but I haven't really evaluated the other alternatives.

Comment: [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlabs.com/sqlitemanager.php) from SQLabs. I haven't used it myself, yet, but it looks quite good from the feature list and screenshots. It costs $49.

Comment: I use SQLite Manager all the time. Marco, the developer is very helpful. Well worth the money

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com). It used to have a free "Lite" version whih is unfortunately not available any more. The pro version supports several important DB engines, not only SQLite. I am currently using the 30-day free eval version.

Answer (score 1):

Razorsql can handle many kinds of databases.

Comment: I can attest this is a great product, as I used it through the trial period.

Comment: Looks great, but Base costs only $20 where this costs $70.