# .db file and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am having real issues with a .db file its around 20gb in size with three tables and the rest data.

I am on a mac so i am having to use some crappy apps but it wont open in Access.

Does any one know what software will produce a .db file and what software will allow me to open it and export it as a CSV or MySQL file ?

Also if the connection was interrupted during transit could this effect the file ?

Answer (score 4):

Since mac is BSD-based now, try opening a terminal and executing the command `file /path/to/large/db` -- it should tell you at least what file type the DB is, and from there you can determine what program to use to open it.  It might be MySQL, might be PostGreSQL, might be SQLite -- file will tell you.

Example:

```
$ file a.db
a.db: SQLite 3.x database

$ file ~/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle/amarok/tracks.{frm,MYD,MYI}
~/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle/amarok/tracks.frm: MySQL table definition file Version 10
~/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle/amarok/tracks.MYD: data
~/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle/amarok/tracks.MYI: MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 1
```

So it's SQLite v3?  Then try

```
sqlite3 /path/to/db
```

and you can perform pretty much standard SQL from the CLI.  [At the CLI, you can type `.tables` to list all the tables in that DB](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7). -- Or if you prefer a GUI, there are a few options listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor).  Accepted answer was [SQLite manager for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817).

Then you could [drop tables](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) or [delete](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) as you see fit.

Here's an example of dumping a csv to stdout:

```
$ sqlite3 -separator ',' -list a.db "SELECT * FROM t"
3,4
3,5
100,200
```

And to store it to a file -- the > operator redirects output to a file you name:

```
$ sqlite3 -separator ',' -list a.db "SELECT * FROM t" > a.csv
$ cat a.csv # puts the contents of a.csv on stdout
3,4
3,5
100,200
```

`-separator ','` indicates that fields should be delimited by a comma; `-list` means to put row data on the same line, using the delimiter; `a.db` indicates which db to use; and `"SELECT * FROM t"` is just the SQL command to execute.

Comment: Its a SQlite Version 3 , 

What is the best way to open a 20gb .db file on a mac ?

I would not been to bothered if I had to cut it up 3 times for each table.

Comment: So how could I issue the command to copy the .db file to a CSV ?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, 

I got this "Unknown-00-1f-5b-c7-49-5c:~ MacHome$ sqlite3 -separator ',' -list /Users/MacHome/Desktop/tpb/tpb.db "SELECT * FROM  cat"
100,Audio
101,Audio > Music
102,Audio > Audio books
103,Audio > Sound clips
104,Audio > FLAC
199,Audio > Other

ETC ETC"

Does this mean it is complete if so were has it placed the CSV ?

Comment: That just wrote the csv to your console - see edited post for how to redirect to a file.

Comment: Do I have to wait for the first command to be processed then continue with "$ cat a.csv # puts the contents of a.csv on stdout
3,4
3,5
100,200" ?

Comment: No, the cat command just shows it to the terminal.  You could open it with whatever program you want after it's been saved.  Go do some research on using the terminal -- Google will have much information for you.

Comment: Mark , 

When I execute the last command you told me I am missing the headers of each table is there a reason for this ?

Comment: Pass the `-header` option on the command line to turn headers on.  More info if you run `sqlite3 --help`.

Comment: Where would I put it in the following command 

"$ sqlite3 -separator ',' -list a.db "SELECT * FROM t" > a.csv
"

?

Comment: It should be `sqlite3 -header -separator ',' -list a.db "SELECT * FROM t" > a.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac user but if it's a SQLite file I've heard great things about [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/).

Comment: It crashed every time I try to use it do you think that might because I havent paid for it ?

Comment: No, lol. It's probably a memory overflow due to the big size of your database. Try searching for alternatives @ alternativeto.net

Comment: Maybe RazorSQL http://alternativeto.net/desktop/razorsql/?profile=mac&platform=mac

Comment: If I only wanted to make it a CSV so I can then shrink it and put it into MySQL could Terminal do it for me ? every piece of software seems to struggle and crashes

Comment: It most surely can, however I've never done it before and I suggest you google about it: http://www.google.com/search?q=dump+sqlite+to+csv