# Best SQLite administrator

Tags: sqlite

What is the best SQLite administrator for iPhone SQLite databases?

```
                Developer         User Administrator
Mac                x                   x
Windows            x                   x
iPhone/iPad        x                   x
```

Could you get to app databases with and admin on the phone?

Comment: Also, perhaps you should revisit some of your previous questions and accept some answers.

Comment: The table - I need a table for myself, and perhaps to tell others how it works.  
iPhones are usually developed in a Mac-environment, but it seems tools on Macs are more difficult than on Windows.

Comment: May I suggest looking at this question and its chosen answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor

Answer (score 2):

See this list in the official documentation:

https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html#sh_mark_6