# Is there a sqlite gui that supports custom collations?

Tags: sqlite

I have a custom collation sequence that I named NOCASE_UTF8 that I'm using in a couple sqlite dbs for an iPhone app I made. I would love to use a sqlite gui on my Mac to be able to manage my dbs rather than doing it all through my app's C code. I would also like to not have to roll my own gui tool JUST to handle this one problem.

I've tried a couple sqlite guis and neither one allows you to interact with collation unless I made a horrible oversight. I've tried using SQLite Manager and Base to insert rows into my tables that use the custom collation. Both just blow up with the error message "no such collation sequence: NOCASE_UTF8". I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor) for a list of guis but nothing I've read of the guis talks about custom collation support.

Am I just SOL or is there a sqlite gui out there with custom collation support?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this solution is open source so if it doesn't support custom collation, you could add it yourself... if you dare.

http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/

There are very few options for Mac OS in this category.  I've always used the Firefox addon, but I've never used weird collations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but 1. I don't know php and am not super interested in learning it and 2. that sounds like overkill. I think I'm just going to leave the collation sequences out of table creation and move them into my selects. It's not super critical that the collation work outside the app so I think this is probably the best approach for me.