# How to launch sqlite Database browser from the command line on Mac OS X

Tags: database, sqlite, unix

I am following a tutorial for Ruby on Rails3. The author types the following which launches sqlite Database Browser and opens the specified database.

```
open db/development.sqlite3
```

What can I do to configure my system to do the same? I am on Mac OSX 10.6

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I mean launche the GUI program Sqlite Database Browser with the line open db/development.sqlite3. Sorry I should have been clearer.

Comment: found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463929/couldnt-find-a-file-descriptor-referring-to-the-console-on-ubuntu-bash-on-win) with xdg-open command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X, the command `open FILE` will perform the same action as double-clicking the file in Finder. If it is not working, it's because the file type needs to be associated with the application:

1. Select the file in Finder.
2. Select "Get Info" from the File menu.
3. In the "Open with:" section, pick the application you want.
4. Optionally, click "Change All..." to use that app for all files with same extension.

Afterward, `open` will launch that app with that file.

If you don't want to change the type, you can also tell the `open` command which app to use:

```
open -a "App Name" FILE
```

Type `man open` to see the manual page which will explain in more detail how it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can install `sqlite3` command line tool from MacPorts or you can download, satisfy dependencies and compile it yourself.

If you have macports installed, execute command

```
sudo port install sqlite3
```

then

```
sqlite3 anyfile.db
```

to launch command line interface on specified sqlite3 file.

Comment: Actually what I want is to launch the GUI sqlitedatabase browser from the command line. I should have been clearer.

Comment: There are some other mac os x apps for browsing SQLite in GUI. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor

Answer (score -3):

Download    sqlite-shell-osx-x86-3071401.zip from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
Double click the zip, then double click sqlite3.