# "Couldn't find a file descriptor referring to the console" on Ubuntu bash on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have a problem with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. If I type "open (filename)" on Mac terminal, it opens the file with the right program but if I try to use it on Windows bash, it says: "Couldn't find a file descriptor referring to the console".

I have also tried xdg-open and gnome-open but none of them works. How can the issue be fixed, and how does the open command work?

Comment: You could try using the batch file command `start`. However, that is an internal command to `cmd`. So you need to wrap it as `cmd /c start "" "filename"`

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: What error do you see with command mentioned above? BTW, you might need to convert paths from Windows to Linux or vice versa.

Comment: `open(1)` on Linux is a deprecated alias for `openvt(1)`.

Answer (score 73):

Instead of open u can use `xdg-open` which does the same thing, independently of application i.e. pdf, image, etc. It will open a new virtual terminal (I have tried this on Linux)

Example:

`xdg-open ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/myPic.jpg`

`xdg-open ~/Docs/holidays.pdf`

Answer (score 43):

For linux, use **xdg-open**. **open** is for Mac OS. **open** in linux is an name alias of openvt (open virtual terminal).

To simplify it, you can append the following line to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc depends on the shell you are using.

```
alias o="xdg-open" # o stands for open
```

Then next time you can just type like the following to reduce some keyboard strokes.

`o file_name.pdf`

Comment: Off-topic: I also define my remote commands like that!
`s` shows running jobs
`p` prints most recent output
`o` displays the file

Comment: Alternatively, define `open` as an alias or function to make all your normal scripts work alike on OS X and Linux. https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/7d9b685e9ba1edba243fc89e78095b27c5ace37b#diff-faf0d10d25b6ac7fcd15598e065e4f66R21

Answer (score 24):

That's because `open` is a Mac specific command, it is not available under Linux (ubuntu), Mac `open` can execute a file (if the file is executable), or open the file into a text editor (if it is a document or text file) or open a directory.

Comment: Makes sense. But there is similar command on Linux and Ubuntu called "xdg-open" so I think there is a way to implement it on Windows bash as well @hcheung. I just installed xdg-utils package but it opens files and folders inside bash. Is there any way to open files through windows programs?

Comment: I'm window-free for more than 10 years! Hope someone could help.

Comment: I have a `/bin/open` app on my Linux OS. There indeed is an `open` cmd for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For opening a file to write in Ubuntu on Windows bash, you can type -:

> nano *filename.txt*

The above command will allow you to write/edit in the file after which, you can use *ctrl+x* and then press *'y'* to save. Check/view the file content using -:

> cat *filename.txt*