# SQL statement containing semicolon causes error

Tags: sql, sqlite

It's already been reported by a few people that a semicolon inside a quoted string can cause an SQL error.

My current setup is an SQLite 3 database and I'm trying to perform an insert, one of my new data's fields contain some HTML, and as part of that I have html entities which end in a semicolon, example - `&egrave;`

A simple stripped down example query I'm trying is the following:

```
insert into my_table (some_field) values ('Hello; world');
```

And the errors I am getting are:

1)

```
insert into my_table (some_field) values ('Hello
Error : unrecognized token: "'Hello"
```

2)

```
world')
Error : near "world": syntax error
```

So the SQL engine is obviously seeing the semicolon in `Hello; world` and interpreting it as an end of statement. I've asked a few other people to test this and some people this works find when they are using a SQLite GUI which leads me to believe it's just an SQL setting that needs changing.

It seems that at least by default the SQL engine wants semi colons only for end of statements, does anyone know how to change this?

It's very strange, please try the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS djp;
CREATE Table djp ("mykey" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" VARCHAR(25));
INSERT INTO djp (name) VALUES ('This is test two; OK?');
SELECT * FROM djp;
```

Please note that if I insert without specifying which fields to insert (making my auto increment a little pointless), the error doesn't happen...

```
INSERT INTO djp VALUES (1, 'This is test two; OK?');
```

Comment: Using the stand alone `sqlite3.exe`, I had no trouble inserting a single-quote string with a semi-colon. What language are you trying to run this code from?

Comment: Right now I am using Navicat to perform a query onto my SQLite db.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does `"This is test two; OK?"` fair any better?

Comment: No it doesn't, the really interesting thing is this causes a problem when I'm specifying which fields to update, so `INSERT INTO djp VALUES(....)` is okay, but updating just name field: `INSERT INTO djp (name) VALUES ('hello;world')` generates a problem. This is very weird. Did you try my example SQL from the updated question? Please do...

Comment: Yes, I cut & paste your example (upvote just for that) and it executed fine. The quirk you mentioned is bizarre. I don't know Navicat, so I won't be much help...

Comment: So you're saying that for you my problem code is working as expected?

Comment: Correct. `'This is test two; OK?'` was added and returned just like any other text.

Comment: Great, maybe it's just Navicat with a bug. Thank you for your help. It looks like Navicat has a bug, I will report to them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16268/discussion-between-daniel-and-sam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I ran your code example in the stand alone `sqlite3.exe` engine and it executed as any other text would (with or without the semi-colon). Since you pointed out with the `INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ()` and `INSERT INTO Foo (column) VALUES ()` quirk, I agree that this isn't a problem with your code, it is a bug with Navicat.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Sam's answer the issue is the SQLite editor and not SQLite itself.  In the case of this question the problem was with Navicat (Note: now patched as of 10.1.2).  I ran into the same issue but for me it was with the same issue with SqlQuery.

I struggled with this until I realized many of the free SQLite clients/editors do not have with semicolon in string support!

I eventually found [MesaSQLite](http://www.desertsandsoftware.com) which supports semicolons within strings and is free (but has some other slight drawbacks).

I am posting this answer because I found this *question* easily while search engining around but I did not find the answer as easily.  Best of luck to others who come across this.

Other questions that might help:

[Mac SQLite editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor)

[What are good open source GUI SQLite database managers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)

Remember, the problem is not SQLite! :)

Comment: Note that Navicat has released an update (10.1.2) and this sorts out this problem,

Comment: @Daniel Updated the answer so more people know that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply have to tell SQLite what your escape character is at the end of the SQL statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RevenueChange LIKE '%0\%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The LIKE will match values such as 30%, 140%, etc. And I think you are using `PHP` right? Why not use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $name = 'one';
    $value = 1;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with special characters.

Comment: I am not using PHP, thanks for your answer, I am using SQLite and actually I'm running my queries both from the command line and from an SQLite GUI (Navicat) - please see my updated question with a sample table which causes the problem.