# SQLite3 browser for mac

Tags: ios, macos

Please i want program for mac to make sqlite3 database with db3 extension.
I test sqlite manager from firefox add-on but the extension is sqlite.
Please give me name or link to download it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac SQLite editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100959/mac-sqlite-editor)

Comment: Mr.lime the answer of the question in your link is the SQLite Manager from fire fox . and i wrote in my question give me any program Except SQLite Manager fire fox.

Comment: There are many other options suggested in other answers to that question, if you scroll past the first one.

Comment: You can, of course, use the `sqlite3` command from the Mac command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use **[SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).**

It's not perfect but it's free, open-source and works for most usage scenarios. Usability could be better though.

I have never had a problem with using whatever extension I want for the DB file. `.sqlite3`, `.db`, `.db3`, they should all work without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Lets you browse your sql lite database

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/